# Loading different controllers with the same conditional URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm using MEAN and I'm trying to redirect the user to different pages (different controllers as well) using a conditional URL like www.domain.com/#!/:path

I'll explain myself a little more better.

I've got three different packages (users, organizations and events), but all the packages can be accessed by the same parametrized URL (www.domain.com/#!/:path). Path is a field stored in database and each record belonging to each package has its own path. Path is unique, of course.

What i want to do is to detect if the URL the user is visiting belongs to users, organizations or events, for loading the proper page. For that, I have to query the database for checking if that :path is stored in users, organizations or events model. According to the result of that query, just redirecting to the proper controller/page.

I don't know how to accomplish that exactly in AngularJS side. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

Finally, i got it working doing something like this:

```
// states for my app
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'system/views/index.html'
  })
  .state('entity', {
    url: '/:path',
    template: 'Loading...',
    controller: function ($scope, Global, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/checkUrl/' + $stateParams.path
      })
      .then(function (result) {

        $scope.global = Global;

        // Doing entity information accesible globally
        $scope.global.entity = result.data.info;


        // Redirecting to the proper controller/template
        switch ( result.data.type ) {

          case 'users':
            $state.go('user', {reload: true});
            break;

          case 'organizations':
            $state.go('organization', {reload: true});
            break;

          default:

        };

      });
    }
  })
  .state('user', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'users/views/index.html'
  })
  .state('organization', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'organizations/views/index.html'
  });
```

Through `/checkUrl/:path` a request is made to server side for checking if `:path` belongs to users, organizations or events. The response contains the info of that entity and the kind (user, organization, event).

From there, it's just redirecting according to the entity matched.

Comment: Why not stick to the traditional path system of three separate urls: '#!/users/:id', '#!/organizations/:id' and '#!/events/:id'? This should be easily accomplished with the [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), unless I'm missing some details in your question.

Comment: This way is what client requested us. Personally, i'd develop it using personalized URLs for each package, but client orders. If i don't find any kind of successful answer, i'll have to use your approach. But in the meantime, i'll try to find a way.

Comment: you can create a pathController then redirect from this controller to specific pages

Comment: Can you give me a little insight or just passing a useful link about it? I understand the approach, but i doubt about how to do it.